# How to find image uploaded status from url or file name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloudinary

I have used cloudinary. I have uploaded an image to cloudinary and I want to get that image status from cloudinary that it is uploaded or not using cloudinary URL or from image name.

I am using jQuery and I want to display a list of images with their status uploaded on cloudinary. I have URL stored in my database.

Can anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: Their API documentation can be found here: http://cloudinary.com/documentation

Comment: @GibboK In documentation shows that how to display image from URL, but not showing status of image uploaded or not. I want to request cloudinary that they can give me response of image with status.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the upload response (JSON) for this matter, as described [here](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612531-How-can-we-utilize-the-upload-response-when-using-the-jQuery-uploader-).

Comment: It happens some time that i get response that image is uploaded but it does not. That's why i have stored url to database and want to check again if it's already exists or not on cloudinary.

Comment: Can you share a specific example of a valid response where the resource actually didn't exist? Have you tried looking for these specific resources using the Admin API?
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#details_of_a_single_resource.